# How to get an image to appear in a header, fully sized when the screen is wide enough but centered when the screen is too thin?

Tags: html, css

I have an image I am using in the header of a website, and on a computer the image takes up the whole width as intended. When the site is displayed on mobile devices however, it scales down and only shows the far left side of the image.

```
.backimage {
padding:20px;
background-image:url(background.jpeg);
width:100%;
height:35%;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size:cover;
}
```

Is there some code I can add to center the image when the width is too small for the whole image? Thanks, if more information is needed I will provide.

Answer (score 0):

use @mediaquery

```
  @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .backimage {
       padding:20px;
       background-image:url(background.jpeg);
       width:50%;
       height:35%;
       margin-left: 0px;
       background-repeat:no-repeat;
       background-size:cover;
    }
  }
```

If the browser window is 600px or smaller, the image width will be 50%.

if you want different styling for different size, you can use

```
  @media only screen and (max-width: 900px) {
    .backimage {
       padding:20px;
       background-image:url(background.jpeg);
       width:70%;
       height:35%;
       margin-left: 0px;
       background-repeat:no-repeat;
       background-size:cover;
    }
  }
```

If the browser window is 900px or smaller, the image width will be 70%.